# how to modify arithmetic expression for different result range

Tags: logic, logical-operators

I need to modify an existing random-based arithmetic expression, to achieve a different range of resulting values.
The equation is `random % 10`, with a range of results from 0 to 9.
I need resulting values between 5-9.
Is there an arithmetic expression for this?

Please only propose changes to the equation.
(Editors note: This probably means to avoid coding constructs, e.g. `if(...)`.)

Comment: Readability benefits from careful phrasing and correctness. Do not use SMS speech. Take your time editing your question. Avoid the impression of considering your own time more valuable than that of potential answerers. A separate issue is the potential impression that the question has been posted instead of experimenting yourself or searching the web. Show your failed experiments. If they are many, even if far off, your effort will be appreciated. If possible name your specific problem/obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **(random % 5) + 5**

Here **(random % 5)** will generate a value between 0 & 4 inclusive. Then you just add 5 to the answer to get the values between 5 & 9 inclusive